# How can I use a loopback device (or something similar) with epoll?

Tags: c, linux, loopback, epoll

I am writing a small library module which accesses the UART and uses epoll to react on incoming data. It works fine with the tty device, however, I want to write test cases for this module. When I open a loop device (/dev/loop*) instead of a tty, epoll_ctl fails with EPERM. The Manual states:

> EPERM: fd does not support epoll.

So the question is: Is there any kind of loopback device which could be used with epoll?

---

Here's a gist with my example code: https://gist.github.com/0815fox/9ce9f19648ce2dc9b23b37dbbb9adab4

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <linux/loop.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static int getFreeLoopDevice(const char * backingfileName) {
    int loopctlfd, loopfd, backingfile;
    long devnr;
    char loopname[4096];

    loopctlfd = open("/dev/loop-control", O_RDWR);

    devnr = ioctl(loopctlfd, LOOP_CTL_GET_FREE);

    close(loopctlfd);
    return devnr;

    sprintf(loopname, "/dev/loop%ld", devnr);

    loopfd = open(loopname, O_RDWR);

    backingfile = open(backingfileName, O_RDWR);

    ioctl(loopfd, LOOP_SET_FD, backingfile);
    return loopfd;
}

static int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity) {
    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error %d from tcgetattr", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
    // as \000 chars
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
    tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                        // no canonical processing
    tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                        // enable reading
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tty.c_cflag |= parity;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error %d from tcsetattr", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void set_blocking (int fd, int should_block) {
    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "error %d from tggetattr", errno);
        return;
    }

    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = should_block ? 1 : 0;
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    if (tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
        fprintf (stderr, "error %d setting term attributes", errno);
}

static void * uart_thread(void * handle) {
    const int uartHandle = *(int*)handle;
    char buffer[100];
    // the epoll stuff:
    const int ePollFileDescriptor = epoll_create(1);
    struct epoll_event ePollEvent;
    ePollEvent.events = EPOLLIN;
    ePollEvent.data.fd = uartHandle;
    const int epoll_ctl_result = epoll_ctl(ePollFileDescriptor, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, uartHandle, &ePollEvent);
    if (epoll_ctl_result) perror("epoll_ctl\n");
    for (;;) {
        static struct epoll_event events[1] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
        const int eventCount = epoll_wait(ePollFileDescriptor, events, 1, -1);
        if (eventCount < 0) {
            perror("epoll_wait\n");
        } else {
            const int bytesRead = read(uartHandle, buffer, 99);
            if (bytesRead >= 0) buffer[bytesRead] = 0;
            else buffer[0] = 0;
            fprintf(stderr, "Buffer: %s\nBytesread:%d\n", buffer, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {
    // working:
    //    char *portname = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    //    const int uartHandle = open (portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    // not working:
    const int uartHandle = getFreeLoopDevice("/tmp/my-loop-back");

    if (uartHandle < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error %d opening: %s\n", errno, strerror (errno));
        return errno;
    }

    set_interface_attribs (uartHandle, B115200, 0);  // set speed to 115,200 bps, 8n1 (no parity)
    set_blocking (uartHandle, 0);                // set no blocking

    // the pthread stuff:
    pthread_t threadHandle;
    const int pthread_create_result = pthread_create( &threadHandle, NULL, uart_thread, (void *) &uartHandle);

    while (1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "writing to uart\n");
        write(uartHandle, "hello!\n", 7);
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and of course please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And don't forget to make questions *self-contained*. Links can go stale and make the question worthless. This site isn't only for helping you right now, but also to help others with the same or similar problem in the future.

Comment: The example is already minimal. You cannot set up a UART with less. And you cannot write an meaningful epoll test without using threads. And you cannot set up a loopback device without requesting one. So: do you expect me to copy and paste the code from the gist into the question? Also the code is not necessary to answer the question, but it helps in case someone wants to have a base for experiments. So please help me, be more concrete about what you don't like. It's a clear question (see title).

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude - Good message, but it may have a gap (I never noticed it before). Maybe *"please try to create a..."* → *"please try to include a..."*.

Comment: To someone who is less familiar with stackoverflow it is not a good message at all! It does not state what his problem with my question is. My next question will be as "bad" as this one, because I still do not know what his beef is. Actually for me as a newcomer it feels uncomfortable to ask for help here and I will probably choose a different place in future. It's not, that I am not willing to learn. It's more that it is really frustrating if you are just told, that your question is bad without being told why exactly. Maybe those "highly awarded" members are not aware of how newcomers feel.